# Scripting postgresql Remote pg_dump to localhost

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

Is there a way to `pg_dump` a remote table?  This is basically what I'm trying to do:

```
myfile='/volumes/drive2/PG_backups/alpha_PG_dbname_'`date +%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M`'.sql'
pg_dump -h server.local -U adminuser -w dbname > $myfile
```

This throws an error indicating `connection to database "dbname" failed: no password supplied`, but I have that username in the `.pgpass`:

```
# hostname:port:database:username:password
*:5432:dbname:adminuser:thisismysecret
```

I'm relying on this `.pgpass` to provide the password.  `hostname` is set to `*` so the request coming from my workstation should work.

Why is this not working?

Comment: Since I'm initiating `.pgpass` on my workstation, that's where the password should be set up, not on the server.  Trying that tomorrow.  Also versions need to match up (major iterations) otherwise `server version mismatch`.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in a comment, workstation version and server version have to match on major iteration version (i.e. 10.x) and `.pgpass` is the workstation version that provides passwords.